# ESP32 bootstrap pins power consumption

Tags: gpio, esp32, power-consumption, bootstrap, current-sink

The other day, I tried that connect to GPIO15 and GPIO5 GND with 26.7 kohm pull down resistor despite having a internal pull-up beacuse of IO obligation. I had no problems during a booting.

**Please firstly read in below question link :)**

Related my question: [ESP32 boot strapping pins problem (GPIO15 and GPIO5)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622750/esp32-boot-strapping-pins-problem-gpio15-and-gpio5)

**At now, I have question mark about during a deep sleep. Does esp32 draw unexpected current due to default internal pull up resistors when it sleeps? For example: little output sink current from +3V3 to GPIO15 or GPIO5.**

I read datasheet more. I found the document I highlighted in yellow below. I am confused. I just wanted to put my mind at ease and I want to ask you. I want to clarify this before I send it to manufactoring.

[image]